# How to write a lambda to get one property based on another property in an object

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to do what I thought would be a very simple think using Linq lambda, it probably is, but I can't find an example in any tutorial.

I have a simple class with a few properties.  I want to get a list of one of the properties based on the value on another value in that class.

Below is an example of the code, using Linq to get the correct results:

```
public class Client
{       
    public int ClientId { get; set; }


    public int ClientWorth { get; set; }


    public strin ClientName { get; set; }       
}
.
.
.
.
List<Client> allClients = this.GetAllClients();

List<string> richClients = (
                    from c in allClients
                    where c.ClientWorth > 500
                    select c.ClientId.ToString()).ToList();
```

Can someone tell me how to do this using a lambda
I can do the following:

`List<Clients> richClients = allClients.Where(x => x.ClientWorth >500)`

Which give me a list of all clients, but I would like to get a string list back with just the client ids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After filtering by client worth value you should *project* results - i.e. select only client id value:

```
allClients.Where(c => c.ClientWorth > 500).Select(c => c.ClientId.ToString()).ToList()
```

Further reading: [Enumerable.Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Sergey, that's what I was looking for I had tried a .All, it hasn't occurred to me that I could use a select with more criteria.  Thanks for the quick response also

Comment: @AidanO LINQ is well-documented - consider to use MSDN if some operator will be unclear for you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396